How to select columns and _count in Prisma
When using TypeScript with Prisma, and a model as I've defined below, I have found that this is valid and returns to me all my data including all columns in emailAccount.
    const emailAccounts = await prisma.emailAccount.findMany({
      include: {
        _count: {
          select: { folders: true, emailRules: true, RulesProcessedHistory: true },
        },
      },
    });

But, when I include the select for just the id column, I get this typescript  error:
TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and id does not exist in type EmailAccountInclude<DefaultArgs
    const emailAccounts = await prisma.emailAccount.findMany({
      include: {
        id: true,
        _count: {
          select: { folders: true, emailRules: true, RulesProcessedHistory: true },
        },
      },
    });

I believe I'm following the example directly from the docs.
Why am I getting this error, and how can I just select id without all the other columns while still getting my counts?
Prisma Model Follows:
model EmailAccount {
  id                    String                  @id @default(uuid())
  email                 String                  @unique
  name                  String                  @default("")
  imapServer            String                  @default("")
  imapPort              Int                     @default(993)
  imapSecure            Boolean                 @default(true)
  smtpServer            String                  @default("")
  smtpPort              Int                     @default(465)
  smtpSecure            Boolean                 @default(true)
  dateCreated           DateTime                @default(now())
  dateUpdated           DateTime                @default(now())
  active                Boolean                 @default(false)
  passwordEncrypted     String                  @default("")
  passwordIV            String                  @default("")
  passwordAuthTag       String                  @default("")
  passwordKey           Int                     @default(0)
  keyRotationDate       DateTime                @default(now())
  keyRotationFrequency  String                  @default("")
  keyNextRotationDate   DateTime                @default(now())
  KeyRotationStatus     String                  @default("NeverRotated")
  StorePassword         Boolean                 @default(true)
  MaxToRetrieve         Int                     @default(100)
  emailRules            EmailRule[] // Relation to EmailRule records
  folders               Folder[] // Relation to Folder records
  RulesProcessedHistory RulesProcessedHistory[] // Relation to RulesProcessedHistory records
}


The explanation
include is used to select data from relations. In your case, if you want to only return emailAccount.id, you should use select, not include.
Both select and include can't be used at the same time at the same level:

Note that you cannot use select and include on the same level.
[..]
Instead, use nested select options

https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/relation-queries#select-specific-relation-fields
The solution
You can move the _count statement inside a top level select - I believe this should work:
const emailAccounts = await prisma.emailAccount.findMany({
  select: {
    id: true,
    _count: {
      select: { folders: true, emailRules: true, RulesProcessedHistory: true },
    },
  },
});

